# PHP ZipArchive doesn't create zip, except when ran manually with php command

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, apache2, php-ziparchive

Past few hours under the bridge and the zip creation code I'm working with will only create the zip if I run it from a ssh terminal using the php command as in:
    php zipcreate.php
So I know the code works. I'm running this on a ubuntu debian amazon ec2 server. All the relevant files are owned by user ubuntu, the user I'm logged in as when I execute the script manually. It will not work for the life of my when I execute the script from the browser via the sites url. The page loads but no zip.

I've even changed the following lines in etc/apache2/envvars to user ubuntu with no success.
    export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
    export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

What in the world am I missing. I'm pretty sure I'm not duplicating a question on stack overflow since I've read them all by now.

BTW, here's the zip code just in case:
    $files = array('test.txt');
    $zipname = 'file.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();

Comment: Check permissions and privileges on the folder where you're trying to save the file

Answer (score 0):

If you can run it as your user but can't with you web app, it means apache's user (www-data) can't write in this directory.

You have to grant www-data write permission on your target directory:

```
chmod +w /your/target/directory
```

A more secure way to do it is to change your directory ownership and permissions:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /your/target/directory
chmod 775 /your/target/directory #change it if you need
```